# Power-set in Hypercube: historical background of indexing each term like Hasse Diagram?

Tags: reference-request, math-history, order-theory, axioms, visualization

My instructor wants references about the indexation over the hypercube, related question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129613/by-which-pkg-to-visualize-a-hypercube-graph), he does not believe that I was the first who used it -- **[update]** thanks to a comment, the name is *Hasse Diagram* for posets. I have seen similar indexation in set-theory related to power-sets like the below. So

> *what is the historical background about naming vertices in a hypercube?*

**Example with the 3th Hypercube and the power-set of {1,2,3}**

[image]

**Helper questions**

> 1. *Is there someone who worked with power-sets and the [axiom of power-set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_power_set) or [Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_axioms) that used similar notation?*
> 2. *Is this somehow related to traversing a hypercube and anti-chains in a poset?*

Comment: I don't know how this is even remotely a set theoretical thing. Maybe graph theoretical, or group theoretical?

Comment: I still feel like this has absolutely nothing to do with set theory. I do agree with the assertion that this is the power set of a three elements set, but it strikes me as something much closer to graph theory, or group theory (as a question about permutations of the graph, or whatnot) than set theory.

Comment: (Also, this is just a cube, hypercubes usually come in four or more dimensions...)

Comment: @AsafKaragila It is the 3th hypercube, feel free to see higher degree hypercubes [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129720/2956). For this question, there is no sense to make any more complicated example. I could do it if I really wanted but it should be now clear that this question about hypercubes and set-theory is clearly linked through power-sets. I think someone who worked with the axiom of power-set must have thought how to index different elements in power-set...

Comment: I can assure you, I have worked uncountably many times with the power set axiom, and I have *never* thought about it in terms of hypercubes. Nor I can think of any set theorist that I know who did...

Comment: @AsafKaragila I have solved puzzles with a guy who was good in set-theory and PhD in combinatorics -- perhaps someone good in combinatoric set-theory and history knows about this :)

Comment: Those are usually just combinatorialists with a set theoretical affinity. Still doesn't make it set theory, though.

Comment: Isn't this just a consequence of the fact that there are $2^n$ subsets of an $n$-element set, for example the set $\{1,\,2,\,3,\,\dots , \, n\},$ and there are $2^n$ vertices of an $n$-dimensional cube?

Comment: In addition to my last comment, perhaps a version of "Pohlke's Theorem" for hypercubes can be applied, if such a result exists. I don't know anything about this topic, but googling the following three words (not phrase search) seems to bring up some possibly relevant things: "Mehrdimensionale" "Axonometrie" "hypercube"

Comment: This seems to be equivalent to the [Hasse diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) of the power set of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, with the partial order given by inclusion. The Wikipedia article has some historical references.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It strikes me as something much closer to lattice theory than group theory.

Comment: Haven't the vertices of the $n$-dimensional hypercube **always** been identified with points in $\mathbb R^n$ whose coordinates are all $0$s and $1$s? Is your question then about the history of associating an $n$-tuple of $0$s and $1$s with a subset of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$?

Comment: @bof about the history of associating an $n$-tuple of 0s and 1s with the powerset of $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$? Perhaps lattice theory, dunno, not an expert on the area.

Comment: This is isomorphic (as a poset or a lattice) to a boolean algebra. IIRC you're in a technical university. Surely you have mates who know this from C-programming: the lattice of $n$-cube is that of the bitmasks of $n$ bits. The join and meet correspond to bitwise OR and AND. But diagrams like this surely predate computers by a comfortable margin.